# Lubuntu 17.10 won't properly boot except through recovery mode

Tags: boot, lubuntu, 17.10, recovery-mode

I decided to install Ubuntu 17.10. The installation was all fine and dandy as well, until I woke up to see Ubuntu stuck on

```
/dev/sdb clean [...]
```

I could tell it was frozen on the boot since my mouse was accessible over the message, and then when I pretended nothing was wrong and blindly typed in my passcode and pressed enter it seemed as if I'd been logged in due to the mouse changing themes.

When I logged in through recovery mode it seemed to work properly though (which is of course how I am able to type this message).  Until I get this fixed I will not be running any code to clean up my installation such as `deborphan`, `autoremove`, or the program    `ubuntu-cleaner`.  If anyone could help out soon so my computer doesn't get overloaded with cache that would be amazing!

*Update!*
The speed was bothering me so I cleaned the deb files and everything else but the `apt autoremove`, old kernel files, and `deborphan`.  Same error, still works in recovery mode.  Actually It is /dev/sda1 clean and according to some posts from earlier users it says it can be fixed through running this command

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

but for me it said it's already installed.

Toughbook cf-19 mk1, 2gb ram, intel core duo 1.06ghz 1024x768 screen resolution.

*Second update*
Seems that if I open and close the laptop on the login it seems to pop up the login screen?  I guess thats a liveable minor inconvenience but nevertheless I would like to find out how to fix this issue properly.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but I can not comment on the post otherwise (sorry):

I'm having the same issue with lubuntu 17.10, which I upgrade from 17.04; it seems that this is what happens when you forgot to disable non supported software from the update manager before upgrading to the new dist. As far as I could read, this can only be fixed by reinstalling OS...

Answer (score 0):

The kernel 4.13+ (including the 4.14) has issues with intel drivers for the eeepc's.
So the solution it's to install the latest 4.12 kernel and disable\uninstall the latest ones.

You can use this tool to download\install\uninstall the kernels:
https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu

You can't uninstall the kernel that it's running, to solve that you have to restart PC, holding shift key after bios splash screen to open the grup options, go to advance options and select the 4.12 kernel as normal boot and when OS finish to initiate, use ukuu to uninstall the 4.13 that come with Lubuntu 17.10

Comment: Can't they just look back at prior kernels and try to apply the compatibility standards to their newer kernels?